# Can you recommend an alternative for Telerik upload contorol?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, upload, image-uploading

I need some similar to Telerik control because this control have problem in opera.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)?

> Uploadify is a jQuery plugin that integrates a fully-customizable multiple file upload utility on your website

Answer (score 1):

[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) is a great multiple file uploader. It was built off of the popular SWFUpload and they added new features to it.

Some of the features that I have found most helpful are:

> The user can upload all the files at once using ctrl + clicking on all of
>   the files
>
> As the files are being downloaded a queue is displayed which
>   shows the files being downloaded including a completeion bar.
>
> As files are completed they are removed from the queue
>
> It also allows you to specify which file types the user is
>   able to download (they can only see the ones you choose)

The main downfall is that it is a flash uploader if that is a problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use Plupload http://www.plupload.com/ as it has some great options.